# ipython has trouble dealing with '+' character

Tags: ipython

I am trying to use ipython as my default shell in linux. %rehashx is executed at startup, so commands in the shell path can be accessed. There are two issues:

1. Filenames that contain "+" cannot be autocompleted
2. Commands that contain "+" cannot be executed

For example:

```
g++ x.cpp
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
#<ipython-input-2-6f1048d865c4> in <module>()
#----> 1 g++ x.cpp                                                                             
#                                                                                              
#NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, where ipython can't tell if you're meaning to run a command or python code, it interprets it as python code. To help it realize this is actually a command you're trying to run, prefix it with "`!`".

```
!g++ x+6.cpp
g++: x+6.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: how can i make python autocomplete filenames that contain the + char?

Comment: autocompletion works for me. what's the file name? what version of ipython?

Comment: version 0.13.2, try this `touch a++.c`, then `ls a+`, then press TAB. All sorts of irrelevant stuff comes up in the terminal, but not the target file a++.c

Comment: right... what I did before, which worked: `touch aaaa++.c` and `ls aaa<tab>`.  but after you enter the `+` it no longer completes it. I don't know if there's a way to bypass that.